# Text paragraphs generation

Tags: model, markov-process

My goal is to generate a whole article. I have ~70 example articles and I was able to generate good-looking and plausible sentences with Markov chains.

However, I don't know how to generate paragraphs now. I thought about topic modeling (LDA), but it does not work well with hundreds of random sentences. Are there better techniques/models that I can use? Producing a coherent paragraph would be a great result already, I don't need a whole text right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a *new paragraph symbol* to your markov process, not only words.

That would be the straightforward solution, your Markov chain should then frequently insert paragraphs at the end of a sentence.

Comment: I didn't think about this. However, wouldn't this make the "new paragraph" decision based on the last word of the last paragraph? Very often the last word is irrelevant in the decision of making a new paragraph and the text is segmented with respect to the concepts in it. Nonetheless I am going to try this solution and see what the results are.

Comment: Consider using a higher order markov chain for producing text. If you only use the predecessor (= the `.` symbol) then you simply get paragraphs inserted randomly inbetween of sentences.